# Close open softkeyboard and activity on backpressed android

Tags: android

When i pressed back key once, the keyboard and the activity must close at once. but my problem is i need 1 pressed to close the keyboard then another press to close the activity. how can i do it once on back pressed.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a done button on keyboard if you press these keyboard will close. Then you close the acticity by pressing the back button.

```
 android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:singleLine="true"
```